# Python crashes (_PyMem_DebugRawFree) when querying MariaDB with SQLAlchemy 2.0

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb, mariadb-connector

Since I don't know whether this problem is caused by a plain syntax error of me or by SQLAlchemy, MariaDB Connector or Python I ask here:

My application worked well with SQLAlchemy 1.4, MariaDB 1.4 and Python 3.10. In order to migrate to SQLAlchemy 2.0 I made adaptions for the ORM part of SQLAlchemy. Python crash occurs with SQLAlchemy 2.0.23, MariaDB Connector 1.1.8, Python 3.12.0, MariaDB 11.1 (also 10.4), Windows 10 x64 22H2

UPDATE: Thanks to the comment from Gord Thompson below I now know that it works with PyMySQL connector. So the problems seems to be in MariaDB connector.

With this table

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
    `id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name`) USING BTREE
)
```

Python crashes with this code inside the MariaDB connector:

```
db = 'mariadb+mariadbconnector://***:***@localhost/test'
engine = sa.create_engine(db)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
class Base(orm.DeclarativeBase):
   pass

class Account(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'accounts'

   _id: orm.Mapped[int] = orm.mapped_column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
   _name: orm.Mapped[str] = orm.mapped_column('name', sa.String)


with Session() as sess:
   sel = sa.select(Account) \
      .where(Account._name == 'My Account')
   res = sess.execute(sel).scalars()
   for acc in res:
      print(acc._name)
```

when calling sess.execute with the following output:

```
C:\Users\Jens\Projects\Mails\Python> c: && cd c:\Users\Jens\Projects\Mails\Python && cmd /C ""C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\python.exe" c:\Users\Jens\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 50504 -- C:\Users\Jens\Projects\Mails\Python\test.py "
Debug memory block at address p=000001BDB62F37D0: API 'r'
    15 bytes originally requested
    The 7 pad bytes at p-7 are FORBIDDENBYTE, as expected.
    The 8 pad bytes at tail=000001BDB62F37DF are FORBIDDENBYTE, as expected.
    Data at p: 39 31 30 30 33 38 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Enable tracemalloc to get the memory block allocation traceback

Fatal Python error: _PyMem_DebugRawFree: bad ID: Allocated using API 'r', verified using API 'm'
Python runtime state: initialized

[...]

Current thread 0x00000edc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 135 in _substitute_parameters
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 306 in execute
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922 in do_execute
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969 in _exec_single_context
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1848 in _execute_context
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1639 in _execute_clauseelement
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 516 in _execute_on_connection
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416 in execute
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 293 in orm_execute_statement
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2190 in _execute_internal
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2308 in execute
  File "C:\Users\Jens\Projects\Mails\Python\test.py", line 22 in <module>
[...]

Extension modules: _wmi, sqlalchemy.cyextension.collections, sqlalchemy.cyextension.immutabledict, sqlalchemy.cyextension.processors, sqlalchemy.cyextension.resultproxy, sqlalchemy.cyextension.util, greenlet._greenlet, mariadb._mariadb (total: 8)
```

It runs without crash when the .where clause in the SQL construct is omitted.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Can you try using `mariadb+pymysql://…` to see if it works any better?

Comment: Yes :-) it works with pymysql. So the problems seems to be in mariadb-connector. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not able to repeat the crash - does it happen with debugpy only?

Comment: I cannot test this in the next days. I do not use a debug compile of Python. However, I have Python Dev Mode enabled (PYTHONDEVMODE), maybe this is a prerequisite?

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to reproduce this bug - crash seems to be caused by a bad reference count when substituting parameters inside the where clause.

I filed a [ticket](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-273) in MariaDB bug tracker and will update my answer once this issue is resolved.

**Update:** Issue has been fixed and will be available in MariaDB Connector/Python 1.1.9

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I'm glad you could find the cause so that it could be fixed. ... And I'm very impressed how fast it was fixed... Best wishes, Jens